# What's the appropriate way to debate a closed question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Recently, Pat closed a question, someone put a comment on the question, asking why it was closed (but didn't vote to reopen) and I responded to the comment saying that I agreed, but also voted to re-open.  Pat said to take the discussion to meta, but I see no obvious way of referencing that question here.  What's the recommended process for this look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A reasonable workflow would be:

1. Create a new question here in meta, entitled something like

   - "Why was my question closed?"
   - "How can I fix this question so that it is acceptable?"
   - **Preferably not**, "OMG, teh m0ds are jerks"  :)
2. Include a link to the question being discussed.
3. Post a link to the meta discussion on the closed question.

**You do not need to be the person who asked the original question to ask about the closing.**

Doing it in meta provides a much nicer focal point for the discussion and encourage more people to contribute thoughts.  Once a question is closed, I'm guessing that many do not look at it any further.

Comment: Bit tricky for new users who do not have the reputation needed to post in meta.  Not a nice way to welcome them.  See it from their point of view: They ask a question about board games, it gets closed, they're told to take it to meta, they don't really know what meta is but they try, they get told that they don't have the rep needed to post in meta.  I'm guessing they go and never return.

Comment: @DanBeale How often has this happened?  Using the search it is pretty easy to figure out.  My initial impression is "very little".